# Project in Solution Added from Hard Link Does Not Show As a Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

So, I'm working with a Solution, `Solution`. I have a project that I use as a library, `Library`. It's located in a dir outside of `Solution`.

#### I did the following:

1. Inside the `Solution` root directory I created a hard link (`mklink /J`), `Link`, to the path for `Project`.
2. I added `Project` to `Solution` using the `Link` as the address, generating a

   `Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Project", "Link\Project.csproj", "{1DE7E580-A7EB-4228-AA72-2110FE7881DD}"
   EndProject`

line in the `Solution.sln` file

3. Added `Project`, **as a reference**, into another project `Project2` that lives inside `Solution`

---

**However**, the library shows up with a `File Not Found` icon in the references list:

[image: Project file is missing]

**If** I include the namespace in a file I get:

```
Error   23  The type or namespace name 'InvoiceGeneratorLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

---

Is VS unable to follow hard-linked project references? What else could be causing trouble?

Answer (score 0):

## Hard-to-spot mistake.

The reason the `Proeject` dll was not being added the `Project2` is because

#### `Project` was targeting .NET 4.5.2

and

#### `Project2` was targeting .NET 4.5

At least, I can say that TIL that you ***can*** use a hard-link to add a project to more than one solution. Not sure if this is best practice, but there it is...